# How to make an 'if' on roman numbered pages and another 'if' on arabic numbered pages

Tags: conditionals, page-numbering, backgrounds

I want to make some conditions on roman pages and another condition on arabic numbered page. (I want to know how to remove the background from specific pages in both numbering categories).

```
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifnum\value{page}>0
\ifodd\value{page}\relax%
\backgroundsetup{% settings for odd-numbered pages
  angle=0,
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=0cm,xshift=-9.7cm]current page) {\includegraphics[scale=1.10]   {Margin2.png}};    %% yshift and xshift for example only
\end{tikzpicture}}
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{% settings for even-numbered pages
  angle=0,
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=0cm,xshift=9.7cm]current page) {\includegraphics[scale=1.10]{Margin2.png}};    %% yshift and xshift for example only
\end{tikzpicture}}
}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial
\fi}
```

EDIT:

```
 \begin{document}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \pagestyle{empty} %No headings for the first pages.
 %% front setting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \input{pg}
 \cleardoublepage
 \pagenumbering{Roman}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \tableofcontents %Table of contents


  \chapter*{\textbf{Introduction}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

  \thispagestyle{plain}

 \large BLA BLA.

 \end{document}
```

I want to remove the bg from the homepage and i want to know how we can remove background from specific pages. 
\NoBgThispage doesn't work here

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see the setup of the roman page numbers?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel See my edited post please

Comment: apologies for the delay

Comment: @luke Your MWE lacks the preamble

Comment: @luke May you add some indication about how you'd want to use this new condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly what you want to do with your condition, so I can't provide a MWE.

Anyway, a simple way to achieve what you want is to define a new "if". Add this line in the preamble:

```
\newif\ifroman\romanfalse
```

Then modify your `\AddEverypageHook` command as follows:

```
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifroman
    % add whatever you want to be printed when page numbering is roman
  \else
    % add whatever you want to be printed when page numbering is not roman (e.g. arabic)
  \fi
}
```

At this point, when you define the page numbering in your document, do it as follows:

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}\romantrue
```

when you want roman numbering, and

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}\romanfalse
```

when you want arabic numbering.

Comment: Many thanks! hope this will bee useful to others

Comment: @luke glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the standard `\pagenumbering` macro for switching to `Roman` or `roman` you can use the in the code defined macros

- `\ifroman` for lowercase Roman numbering,
- `\ifRoman` for uppercase Roman numbering, and
- `\ifRroman` for any Roman numbering.

They have to be used with arguments, for example

```
\ifRroman{<true>}{<false>}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\thepage@Roman{\csname @Roman\endcsname\c@page}
\def\thepage@roman{\csname @roman\endcsname\c@page}
\def\ifroman{\ifx\thepage\thepage@roman\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\def\ifRoman{\ifx\thepage\thepage@Roman\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\def\ifRroman{%
  \ifx\thepage\thepage@Roman
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \ifx\thepage\thepage@roman
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ifroman{roman}{not roman} :
\ifRoman{Roman}{not Roman} :
\ifRroman{Rroman}{not Rroman}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\ifroman{roman}{not roman} :
\ifRoman{Roman}{not Roman} :
\ifRroman{Rroman}{not Rroman}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\ifroman{roman}{not roman} :
\ifRoman{Roman}{not Roman} :
\ifRroman{Rroman}{not Rroman}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]